# Python Inner Join Returns No Rows but Contour Does

Tags: python, foundry-code-repositories, foundry-python-transform

[Contour Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTppz.png)I am using a Code Repository to perform a Python transform. This involves selecting columns from three separate datasets (caufv_df, afpo_df, prps_df) and then inner joining them into one. The first inner join joins on the column "OrderNumber". When I run this join it returns zero rows. However, if I open Contour and do an inner join it returns 7 million Order Numbers that match between the two tables.

I have double-checked the schema to make sure data types match, I've tried different syntaxes for the join, and removing the substring and cast functions. None of these have helped. The other commented out inner join works so I know it isn't my environment or a syntax mistake. Can anyone help?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output


@transform_df(
    Output("redacted file path"),
    caufv_df=Input("redacted file path"),
    afpo_df=Input("redacted file path"),
    prps_df=Input("redacted file path"),
)
def compute(caufv_df, afpo_df, prps_df):
 
 # prep caufv_df for joining
    caufv_df = caufv_df.select(
        F.col('opertn_task_list_no_|_aufpl').alias('aufpl'),
        F.col('object_number_|_objnr').alias('objnr'),
        F.substring(F.col('order_|_aufnr'), 4, 9).cast('integer').alias('OrderNumber'),
        # F.col('order_|_aufnr').cast('integer').alias('order'),
        F.col('technical_completion_|_idat2').alias('completed_date'),
        F.col('order_type_|_auart').alias('Order_Type')
    )

# prep afpo_df for joining
    afpo_df = afpo_df.select(
       F.col('order_item_quantity_|_psmng').alias('Operation_Qty_AFPO'),
       F.substring(F.col('order_|_aufnr'), 4, 9).cast('integer').alias('OrderNumber'),
       #F.col('order_|_aufnr').cast('integer').alias('order'),
       F.col('wbs_element_|_projn').alias('WBS_Element')
    )

# prep prps_df for joining
    prps_df = prps_df.select(
        F.col('wbs_element_|_posid').alias('WBS'),
        F.col('applicant_no_|_astnr').alias('Applicant_Description'),
        F.col('applicant_|_astna').alias('ApplicantName'),
        F.col('wpc_|_zzwpc').alias('WPC'),
        F.col('material_|_zzmatnr').alias('material_zzmatnr'),
        F.col('description_|_post1').alias('Descriptionprps'),
        F.col('customer_code_|_zzccd').alias('CustCode'),
        F.col('wbs_element_|_pspnr').alias('WBS_Element')
    )

# join caufv_df with afpo_df and prps_df to create the final dataframe


    joined_df = caufv_df.join(afpo_df, 'OrderNumber', 'inner')
    #joined_df = afpo_df.join(prps_df, 'WBS_Element', 'inner')
    

    return joined_df
```

Comment: Without seeing the underlying data it can be hard to see why this join is not working. Can you please also share a screenshot of your contour analysis (presumably with data redacted) so we can confirm the analysis matches the code?

Other than that I would suggest confirming that your contour analysis is working with the same datasets and transactions as your Python transform.

Comment: The logic in your code does match the logic in your contour analysis. One possible cause of issue is that you might be using a branched input dataset in your transform, but the master dataset in your contour analysis. If that is the case, you can use the branch selector in contour to select the same branch as your Python transform is running on.

Comment: The branches are both the masters. The join is now returns only two records. I have manually checked a couple of the OrderNumbers and while they match, they are not being pulled into the joined_df. Is there any reason an inner join would not bring in matching OrderNumbers?

Comment: Have you tried to check whether those casting and substring yield the desired output on all the prepro tables?

Comment: i would recommend to use debugger, and in left  panel of debugger you can prefilter input datasets to few samples that you manually checked, and then run the debugger and see if it gets the data, you can also use print() to print values in console. P.s if you dont know, click on left side of code line numbers to set a break point

Comment: especially before the join, you can check the data in console, and see if its in correct format as you desire